# Parsing a Nested Array (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to find an efficient way to do the following :

1) Parse an array.
2) If the element is a single value, store it/echo it.
3) If the element is an array, Parse it and store/echo all of its elements.

An example would be :

$array = array(15,25,'Dog',[11,'Cat','Cookie15'],22)

This would be echo'd as :

15
25
Dog
11
Cat
Cookie15
22

Note : The maximum number of Nested layers of Arrays = 2 (The max is an Array within an Array, not deeper than that).

The code I have made so far is :

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){  
      if(is_array($value))
      {
      <Not sure how to handle this condition! Need to parse the array and echo individual elements>
      }
      else
      {
       echo "Input name : $key Value : $value  ";
      }
}
```

Edit: The following is my dump for the array. The nested elements show blank for some odd reason!

```
string '15' (length=2)

string '25' (length=2)

string 'Dog' (length=3)

array (size=3)
  0 => string '' (length=0)
  1 => string '' (length=0)
  2 => string '' (length=0)

string '22' (length=2)
```

The relevant code is :

```
foreach($_POST as $input) {
 var_dump($input);
}
```

Comment: Where did that array come from?  What created it?  If it's a well-defined format, there surely must be existing code that will do it for you.

Comment: It is an array of answers from a Quiz! There are 3 types of answers, Single Choice (Radio Button), Multiple Choice (Checkbox) and Open Answer (User entered answer). While processing the array, it works well for Single and Open types, but for the checkbox (Which contains an array of the selected answers, and not just a single value), I ran into this problem!

Comment: So you're not actually parsing anything.  You want to know how to handle nested arrays that you've been handed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick

PS.: I edit the call to the function, i was calling it inside a foreach, now i'm just sending $_POST wich is correct.

Second edit: I'm not saving the function inside a variable anymore, instead i'm declaring it.

```
function recursiveEcho($input){
    if (is_array($input)) {
        foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                recursiveEcho($value);
            } else {
                echo "Input name: {$key} Value: {$value}";
            }
        }
    } else {
        // This is a string, there is no key to show
        echo "Input value: {$input}";
    }
};

recursiveEcho($_POST);
```

Comment: This fails when `$input` is a string!

Comment: I just tested it, @ComFreek is Right. If you wouldn't mind, can you please explain why it fails?

Comment: @SainathKrishnan Let's assume the first value of $_POST is a string and `$recursiveEcho` therfore gets passed a string. This won't do anything because `$recursiveEcho` only checks for arrays and does nothing otherwise.

Comment: Oh you meant it that way, I thought you meant it in the context of String/Integer/etc! Thanks for clearing that up!

Got it! Then wouldn't that problem be fixed if the else statement of the inner loop was used in the outer loop as well?

Comment: @SainathKrishnan Correct, but this would be redundant (two echos with the same string and formats). Here is a cleaner solution: http://pastebin.com/8QRDCfM8

Comment: There is a small issue with the code here (Which I am having with all the submitted answers that I've tried!), which is that the nested elements do not have a "Value" (The key prints correctly, but the Value is blank!). I tried it with different array sizes, and the number of elements keeps changing, which means the array is reading correctly. But for some reason the values are just not printing!

Comment: @ComFreek that wouldn't work because variabels $key and $value are not defined. I did it that way supposing that the function will always be called with an array so it will be able to print $key and $value. If it is called with a string, there is no way to show the key of that.

Comment: @EdsonHorácioJunior Yes, you're right. I edited the Pastebin.

Comment: @SainathKrishnan Could you please mention this question including a dump of your array structure in your question, please?

Comment: Sure thing, Will add it in a moment. Interestingly, the dump says that the elements of the array are Empty!

Comment: @EdsonHorácioJunior This is the error I get when I try that code :

Notice: Undefined variable: recursiveEcho ||
Fatal error: Function name must be a string

|| Relevant Line of code :
  $recursiveEcho($value); (Line number 5 in your code)

Comment: @SainathKrishnan did you copy and paste the code the same way i wrote? Because $recursiveEcho function declaration must be before you call it passing $_POST.

To clarify, could you paste your code in pastebin or your question?

Comment: My code looks exactly the way it does in your answer! I just copy and pasted it! The error I am getting is only in the array handling part of it. The remaining non array elements are printing perfectly!

Comment: @SainathKrishnan I did edit the code and now the function is called passing $_POST. I think you copied it before that edit.

Now that it is passing $_POST you should just paste the code outside the loop in your question.

Comment: Yes I know! My only code now is literally just your code within <?php ?> tags! I could put it in pastebin if you want me to, but it is the exact same code that you have here.

Comment: Just for the sake of being absolutely sure, here is my code :

http://pastebin.com/NkFRSXdb

Comment: @SainathKrishnan I edited the answer again, I'm not saving the function inside a variable anymore, instead i'm declaring it.

Comment: Code executes without error now! But same problem! Value of nested array elements is blank! :(

Comment: @SainathKrishnan There is an array with 3 empty strings in a var_dump in your question. That behavior is correct, try echoing an empty string, nothing will appear, because it is empty...

Comment: @EdsonHorácioJunior Small detail that I missed on the page that supplies the data. Thank you so much for all the help! Finally got it to work!

Answer (score 3):

Using a RecursiveIteratorIterator and a RecursiveArrayIterator is definitely the cleanest way:

```
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($arr));

foreach ($it as $key => $value) {
    var_dump($key, $value);
}
```

---

This was my old solution:

```
function handle($arr, $deepness=1) {
  if ($deepness == 3) {
    exit('Not allowed');
  }

  foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
      handle($value, ++$deepness);
    }

    else {
      echo "Input name: $key Value: $value ";
    }
  }
}

handle($_POST);
```

Comment: According to the first comment in the doco, recursive function is much faster than RecursiveIteratorIterator: http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php

Answer (score 0):

This will only handle 1 level. To handle `x` amount of levels, you either have to use a recursive function, or keep on nesting `if` statements.

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
   if(is_array($value) {
        foreach($value as $key2 => $value2) {
         echo "Key: " .  $key2 . "value: " .$value2;
        }
    } else {
        echo "key" .  $key . "value: ".  $value;
    }

}
```

Comment: For some reason $value2 is blank for all the elements of the nested array! $key2 has the correct values, though (The array index numbers)