# How to list a multidimensional array in chronological order

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array of professionals, locations, dates and times. How can I list these dates and times within it. And at the same time, if a certain time was chosen, I need to know the date, local_id, and the professional_id it belongs to.

I tried foreach nested and saving each information for each iteration, but in the end it didn't work because I need to display the dates in chronological order.

I've never worked with an array like this, I'm pretty lost.

```
            
Array
(
    [profissional_id] => Array
        (
            [74] => Array
                (
                    [local_id] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [2021-11-09] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [2021-11-16] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 08:00:00
                                            [1] => 08:40:00
                                            [2] => 09:20:00
                                            [3] => 10:40:00
                                            [4] => 12:00:00
                                        )

                                    [2021-11-23] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 08:00:00
                                            [1] => 08:40:00
                                            [2] => 09:20:00
                                            [3] => 10:00:00
                                            [4] => 10:40:00
                                            [5] => 11:20:00
                                            [6] => 12:00:00
                                        )

                                    [2021-11-30] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 08:00:00
                                            [1] => 08:40:00
                                            [2] => 09:20:00
                                            [3] => 10:00:00
                                            [4] => 10:40:00
                                            [5] => 11:20:00
                                            [6] => 12:00:00
                                        )

                                    [2021-12-07] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 08:00:00
                                            [1] => 08:40:00
                                            [2] => 09:20:00
                                            [3] => 10:00:00
                                            [4] => 10:40:00
                                            [5] => 11:20:00
                                            [6] => 12:00:00
                                        )

                                )

                            [5] => Array
                                (
                                    [2021-11-09] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 
                                        )

                                    [2021-11-16] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 
                                        )

                                    [2021-11-23] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 
                                        )

                                    [2021-11-30] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 
                                        )

                                    [2021-12-07] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [33] => Array
                (
                    [local_id] => Array
                        (
                            [3] => Array
                                (
                                    [2021-11-13] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 08:00:00
                                            [1] => 08:30:00
                                            [2] => 09:00:00
                                            [3] => 09:30:00
                                            [4] => 10:00:00
                                            [5] => 10:30:00
                                            [6] => 11:00:00
                                            [7] => 11:30:00
                                            [8] => 12:00:00
                                        )

                                    [2021-11-20] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [2021-11-27] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 08:30:00
                                            [1] => 09:00:00
                                            [2] => 09:30:00
                                            [3] => 10:00:00
                                            [4] => 10:30:00
                                            [5] => 11:00:00
                                            [6] => 11:30:00
                                            [7] => 12:00:00
                                        )

                                    [2021-12-04] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 08:00:00
                                            [1] => 08:30:00
                                            [2] => 09:30:00
                                            [3] => 10:00:00
                                            [4] => 10:30:00
                                            [5] => 11:00:00
                                            [6] => 11:30:00
                                            [7] => 12:00:00
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

This is an example of an array type return I get

Comment: If you can show a complete array in the example, I can help.

Comment: @Newish, I edited the post with a complete array, thanks. Any hint in the direction I should go will help a lot.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18769086/4688321